# Canonical way to schedule with a fixed delay

Tags: project-reactor

Project reactor has a nice API to periodically call some task. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Scheduler.html#schedulePeriodically-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

This API runs every period regardless of how long the task takes. But what if you want to run a task with a fixed delay after the task completes. What is the best practice?

One idea I have is Mono.delay(..).then(task()).repeat().subscribe()
But then you don't get the nice backoff API of the schedular service

Comment: Could you give example what you really want to do?

Comment: The Schdulder API allows you to schedule something periodically. The period between runs remains the same regardless of how the task takes. So if you say run every 10 seconds but the task takes 20 seconds then you will be running two tasks concurrently. Rather you want to say delay 10 seconds after the task completes before running again (like you can with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)